# google chrome does not want to open and cannot uninstall it completely

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kde, firefox, chrome

I found an update for chrome and I updated the system, and the next time I restarted chrome it did not want to open. Nothing was updated except chrome.

When I opened chrome from the terminal nothing appeared to happen until I tried

## 1

`sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox`
this method opened chrome so I tried to change the file:
`/usr/share/google-chrome.desktop`
and switched those lines:

```
"Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" 
"Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U"
```

to

```
"Exec=sudo /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox"
```

saved and yet nothing got resolved.

## 2

`sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`
It got uninstalled but the .config files remained in their place and the .cache also, so I had to delete them myself and then I reinstalled chrome to find that it was not just installed, but actually it signed in to everything I was signed into before I uninstall it; as if I did nothing. I
tried my best for 2 pages of google with nearly the same answer, but to no avail.

## 3

`sudo apt-get install libnss3` tried this one as nearly all solutions was regarding that firefox has updated a file the chrome rely on which is "libnss3" but also this did not help

Is there any solution to completely uninstall chrome from the entire system not just "purge" that did not uninstall and delete all files?
is there any solution to this particular issue?

Comment: Where did you find it? Why Oh why oh why, did you run in with `sudo`? And why with `--no-sandbox`?

Comment: It looks like you missed some config files. You did not delete them all.

Comment: Also have a look at .local and at this (and both of our other folders) in the /root folder, not only in your home. Do a `strace google-chrome-stable` and look for pathes it tries to open, delete everything not in system pathes. Purge Chrome

Comment: Re. "but actually it signed in to everything I was signed into before I uninstall it; as if I did nothing" ... maybe you have your account synced. So first turn off sync, then purge, then delete your ~/.config/google-chrome folder and AFAICT, one shouldn't really run browsers with `sudo` (already mentioned in the first comment).

Comment: yes, i do not run any browser with sudo, it was just my only solution to get chrome running again. the solution was provided in this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOYwEAmCFpc

Comment: i tried to get around to it as i tried to edit the file as he mentioned in the video but it failed, so i had to do it from the terminal first to be sure that it actually works, it worked only when i used 'sudo' with '--no-sandbox'. i really had no idea what does the --no-sandbox does but it worked and unfortunately, all my edits to the file in /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop did not work

Comment: regarding the missed config files, i was so sure that i deleted the files in .cache .config  /opt and some other places that i forgot, i wanted to what exact files that kept chrome installing on my machine each time as if it was never removed, i will try the .local as i do not think i ever touched that file

Comment: @Jaleks there is no files in the `.local` except in the trash

Comment: @Jaleks i tried the `strace google-chrome-stable` and that is what i got
https://ibb.co/7Q3BnPH
and unfortunately i still do not know what to do, i tried `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable` and deleting all the `.` files but to no avail; i do not understand why chrome gets running after the purge as if nothing happened, what files does the "sync" keep to make chrome get working like that

Comment: The screenshot of your strace output is not very helpfull, as it only shows partial output, and no pathes Chrome tries to open are visible. Look for lines starting with 'open' and check the pathes shown later in that lines, which are not only system libs.